# delete in spring project JpaRepository

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

i'm trying to delete some employees from my database 
but i can't.
this is my Repository code:

```
public interface EmployeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employe, Long> {
@Query("delete from Employe e where e.idEmploye=:x")
public Employe deleteEmploye(@Param("x") int idEmploye); }
```

this my controller :

```
@RestController public class EmployeRestService {
@Autowired
private EmployeMetier EmployeMetier;
@RequestMapping(value="/employe3",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public Employe deleteEmploye(@RequestParam int idEmploye) {
    return EmployeMetier.deleteEmploye(idEmploye);}}
```

when i test my controller i get this message

```
{"timestamp": 1495688812536,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
"message": "org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not 
supported for DML operations [delete from org.st.entities.Employe e where 
e.idEmploye=:x]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for 
DML operations [delete from org.st.entities.Employe e where 
e.idEmploye=:x]",
"path": "/employe3"
```

}

Comment: Queries that can change data [need to annotated with `@Modifying`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries) and `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Data JPa, you can only retrieve/ insert a new record by default. So in case if you want to modify/ update/ delete an existing record, then you have to mark your method as @Transactional & @Modifying to instruct Spring that given method can change existing record anytime. So
Try this:

```
public interface EmployeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employe, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from Employe e where e.idEmploye=:x")
    public Employe deleteEmploye(@Param("x") int idEmploye); 
}
```

Comment: it's probably working
but i get another erreur because the id of "employees" is a foreign key in another table 
message :  Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`t_anomalies`.`traitement`, CONSTRAINT `FKafuchse28bfyo9jy5cgxqlybx` FOREIGN KEY (`id_employe`) REFERENCES `employe` (`id_employe`))

Comment: @hich in this case, first you have to delete its child records like in above case its 'message' table, and then your parent record 'employee'